# Create relation 2 model yii2

Tags: model, yii2, relation

How can i create relation between 2 models which have same month and year. My 1st model is OrderTransaction and the 2nd is WeeklyOrder?
Here's my OrderTransaction model code, but it doesn't work. and get this error

> date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Thank you.

```
 public function getWeekly()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(WeeklyOrder::className(), [date("m-Y", "date") => date("m-Y", "created_date")]);
    }
```

> EDIT::

This Code have been work. but i still have to get the data only that data have the same month and year. How Should I do?

```
public function getWeekly()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(WeeklyOrder::className(), [cust_id) => cust_id)]);
    }
```

Comment: I think the error you are getting is straight forward, `date()` is a php date/time function check correct usage at: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Also the second parameter of the `$model->hasOne()` method should array with attribute => attribute2 of the associated models. [Check out the Yii Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#hasMany()-detail)

Comment: @Kalu okey I got it. the date should be in datetime format. I've edit the question, kindly please check out :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom query `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html`

```
...
$query = WeeklyOrder::find();
$query->where(['id' => $transaction->id]);
$query->andWhere(['between', 'date_created', $start, $end]);
$weeklyorders = $query->all();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a join with a condition to join with.

```
public function getWeekly()
{
    return $this-hasOne(WeeklyOrder::className(), ['cust_id' => 'cust_id'])->andOnCondition(['created_date' => date("m-Y")]);
}
```